# No space between buttons 'on next the line'

Tags: html, css, button, spacing

I trying to create buttons with round corner to simulate menus tabs. If the screen is not wide enough, I want the buttons to go to the next line.

My issue is that there is no spacing between the buttons on the first line and those on the following lines:

[image]

I am trying to replicate this issue in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeSeU/1/), but it does not happen there:

[image]

My HTML is:

```
<div>
    <span class="menuButton">Button I Button I Button I</span>
    <span class="menuButton">Button II Button II Button II</span>
    <span class="menuButton">Button III Button III Button III</span>
</div>
```

My CSS is:

```
.menuButton {
    color: #FFFFFD;
    background: #010109;
    margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
    padding: 1px 6px 0px;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    font-family: 'Istok Web', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Why am having this issue in my page and not JSFiddle? I have posted the (work in progress) page [here](http://testing.tostaky.biz/index.html). Shrink the window to 320px wide to replicate the issue.

Comment: Have a look in Chrome Developer Tools by inspecting one of the buttons. See if there is another stylesheet/attribute that the class/tag is inheriting from. For example the line height on your body.

Comment: are there any spaces or did you format the spans to next line?

Comment: @MarkWylde: for example a `div { line-height: 1; }` is enough: http://jsfiddle.net/jeSeU/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're having the issue because the `span`s are naturally inline elements (`display:inline`). If you were to display them as `inline-block` then your margin settings will apply.

```
.menuButton {
    /* ... existing definitons */

    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a line-height to the containing div:

```
<div class="menu">
    <span class="menuButton">Button I Button I Button I</span>
    <span class="menuButton">Button II Button II Button II</span>
    <span class="menuButton">Button III Button III Button III</span>
</div>
```

---

```
.menu {
    line-height: 1.2;
}
.menuButton {
    color: #FFFFFD;
    background: #010109;
    margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
    padding: 1px 6px 0px;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    font-family: 'Istok Web', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kKQ5A/

If that doesn't work, then I'm convinced there is another style applied to the containing element that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `spans` which an inline element as opposed to a block element and hence they don't resepect css styling such as `margin`.
Change your `spans` to `divs` or give the spans the property `display:inline-block;`

Comment: By changing spans to divs, the button expand the whole width, which breaks the layout....